# Trying to find a string in a file

Tags: excel, find, findstr

I'm looking for a free tool that I can use to find a string in an Excel file.  I tried Notepad++, and that didn't work.  I tried Agent Ransack, and that's didn't work.

The intentionally entered a string into an XLSB file, and ran both Notepad++ and Agent Ransack, and neither utility can find the string.  It found it in a Word doc, but not in an Excel file.

Is there a free utility that I can download to find a string within an Excel file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you rename your XLSX file extension to zip, you can access the zip content and you'll find an xml called sharedStrings.xml and you can search in it by using Notepad++, Notepad, or other text editor.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean "you'll find an xml called sharedStrings.xml"?  I converted it to a zip and opened it in Notepad++ and I still don't see the string that I'm looking for, but it's definitely in the file.

Comment: Are you able to extract the files from the zip archive?

Comment: Yes, I see four folders and one XML file.  In each folder there are a bunch of XML files.  I looked at several of those XML files and nothing seems to be what I'm looking for.

It seems Agent ransack is great for finding strings in files other than Excel, but it doesn't find some very obvious strings in Excel worksheets.

Comment: After I extracted the excel, I was able to find the text here \xl\sharedStrings.xml. Do you have this file?

Comment: No, I don't have that.  Maybe it depends on the version of zip that's on your machine.  Oh well.  I guess it's not a huge deal.  I was just curious.  Thanks anyway.